# How to allow www-data apache user to use mkdir() php function?

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions

I'm trying to create folder using `mkdir($pipeline_dir, 0777, true);`, but get the error: `mkdir(): Permission denied`.
I'm using apache2 on ubuntu 14.10 and php 5.5. I have already set up 777 permissions to all files and folders of my project recursivly (`sudo chmod -R 777 myproject`).
Also I've tried to change user to `www-data` (`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data myproject`).

Comment: you must assuming the webserver runs as group www-data.

Comment: can you explain more please. How can I check if web server runs under `www-data` group?

Comment: there is an explaination here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41241/how-to-check-which-apache-group-i-can-use-for-the-web-server-to-write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting 777 permissions on folders is a **bad idea**.

Since you are still getting the error, somewhere the permissions are still wrong.
Try var_dump on the $pipeline_dir and make sure the web user has permissions to write in that parent folder.

Comment: how can I check if www-data user has permissions to write?

Comment: I forgot to tell that my site located at /home/myusername/www. Maybe www-data user can't write to home directory? Maybe it can work only with /var/www? How can I configure it?

Comment: what does the $pipeline_dir value contain?

Comment: $pipeline_dir variable contains: "//min"

Comment: Then that is your problem. Your code tries to create //min which would be on your ubuntu / directory. Change //min to just min and it should work